# ¿Cómo procesar datos sin que mi kernel muera?

Tags: python, optimización, jupyter

Quiero procesar los datos en un [unsupervised.py notebook](https://github.com/aswalin/SQuAD/blob/master/unsupervised.ipynb). Sin embargo, cada vez que lo lanzo parece que el kernel muere.

En particular, es cuando ejecuto esta línea:

```
train['sent_emb'] = train['sentences'].apply(
    lambda x: [dict_emb[item][0] 
    if item in dict_emb 
    else np.zeros(4096) for item in x)
```

Que esta parte de esta funcion:

```
def process_data(train):

    print("step 1")
    train['sentences'] = train['context'].apply(lambda x: [item.raw for item in TextBlob(x).sentences])

    print("step 2")
    train["target"] = train.apply(get_target, axis = 1)
```

Sabiendo que

```
>>>train.shape
(130318, 4)
>>>len(dict_emb)
179862
>>>train.head(3)
    answer_start    context     question    text
0   269     Beyoncé Giselle Knowles-Carter (/biːˈjɒnseɪ/ b...   When did Beyonce start becoming popular?    in the late 1990s
1   207     Beyoncé Giselle Knowles-Carter (/biːˈjɒnseɪ/ b...   What areas did Beyonce compete in when she was...   singing and dancing
2   526     Beyoncé Giselle Knowles-Carter (/biːˈjɒnseɪ/ b...   When did Beyonce leave Destiny's Child and bec...   2003
```

No sé si es possible reducir los recursos que requiere. Tal vez es un problema de memoria? ¿Hay soluciones en línea? Por ahora voy a probar Google Colaboratory...

```
>>> train.memory_usage (index = True, deep = True)
Index                  80
answer_start      1042552
context         130824648
question         15084292
text             10207009
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Lamento no poder ayudarte con lo que planteas, pero un consejo de formateo del código: si la línea es muy larga puedes partirla justo donde se abre el paréntesis de llamada a una función. Mientras no se cierre el paréntesis python sigue leyendo líneas sin que tengas que poner \ al final de cada una.

Comment: @abulafia Ja, gracias de todos modos! ¿Sabes si hay núcleos en línea que se pueden usar para este tipo de trabajo? Actualicé el código de acuerdo con su consejo, finalmente si entendí correctamente.

Comment: Yo últimamente uso mucho [Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/) de Google. Pero es gratis, por lo que supongo que las máquinas (virtuales) en que se ejecuta no serán muy potentes y probablemente tengan menos memoria que la tuya. Y el problema parece de memoria. Puedes probar de todas formas, ya tienen TensorFlow instalado y otras muchas bibliotecas típicas, y mediante el prefijo `!` puedes lanzar comandos del operativo como `apt get` o. `pip install` (pero lo pierdes todo, salvo el propio libro, cuando la VM se apaga)

Comment: Y mi recomendación de formateo iba un poco más allá, decía romper la línea justo tras el `apply(` y poner la parte de `lambda` en otra línea, o en varias líneas. Lo que no está muy claro es cuánto habría que indentar las líneas con los argumentos. Los ejemplos de la biblioteca python usan cuatro espacios (respecto a la línea anterior) pero se permite más. Mira  [aqui](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) por ejemplo.

Comment: @abulafia Sí, el problema del número de espacios se ve entre el segundo y el tercer ejemplo. Así que lo hice simple, puse cuatro. Intento Colaboratorio en el velorio. Pero en realidad, si es un error de memoria, no sé cómo hacerlo

Comment: Si estás ejecutando tu ejemplo en un linux, es posible que [crear un archivo swap y activarlo](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/) pueda evitar que se muera el kernel (aunque el swapping indudablemente ralentizará la ejecución)

Comment: @abulafia Soy un total ignorante sobre el tema. Voy a probar los dos entonces.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81512/discussion-between-marine1-and-abulafia).